# Android - how can I add spacing on the left side of a 2-column layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a 2-column list layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"     
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"

     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
         android:layout_width="275dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="16sp"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
         android:layout_width="25dip"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" 
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But the line: android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" does not produce and effect of adding space.  Also, the screen itself has a left margin but the list does not respond to that as well.

Is there a way to make sure there is spacing on the left side of the screen?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
private List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps;
private SimpleAdapter adapter;

ListView list = null;

    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    // My data
    fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.questions_list,
            new String[] {"train", "to"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL,  R.id.TO_CELL});        
    //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Question>(this, R.layout.user_question_list, questions);

    setListAdapter ( adapter );

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

and later I populate the list like this:

```
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();                                
                            JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(i);

                            String question_id = o.getString("question_id");
                            String question = o.getString("question");
                            String questioner_id = o.getString("member_id");
                            String first_name = o.getString("first_name");
                            String last_name = o.getString("last_name");

                            Question q = new Question ( );
                            q.setQuestion(question);
                            q.setQuestionId(question_id);
                            q.setQuestionByMemberId( questioner_id );

                            q.setAuthorName(first_name + " " + last_name );

                            map.put("train", question);

                            //map.put("from", ">");
                            map.put("to", ">");

                            fillMaps.add(map);
                            questions.add( q );
```

Comment: i don't see any `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"` in your layout

Comment: @vmironov it is on the first few lines.

Comment: and this is a list item? Then show us `getView` method of your adapter. It looks like you have not specified parent in `LayoutInflater.inflate` call

Comment: @vmironov I don't have a getView method written, but I pasted the code I do have in my original question.

Comment: You could also try adding left padding ... If I were to guess though, whatever is the parent of the LinearLayout does not take margins (not all viewgroups do), so that's why it's being ignored...

Comment: @Genadinik, I don't really know why your code doesn't work but as a workaround you can try to wrap your list item with a simple `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change

```
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
```

to

```
 android:layout_paddingLeft="10dp"
```

Comment: It should be android:paddingLeft, not android:layout_paddingLeft